# Which four items will give Varus his maximum damage potential?

Tags: league-of-legends

Varus the archer is on his way into the fields of justice and has some interesting scaling that I'm having trouble groking. The problem I'm running into is conceiving of an item build which optimizes his damage with 4 items (which drops you as a glass-cannon in mid-game or allows for a couple of defensive items to be picked up as part of your complete build).

Obviously, we all (had best) agree that item builds are situational. What I'm looking for is just a base-case situation against, say, some trees or rocks standing around. Forget about the other team's resistances, items, runes, and masteries; just focus on Varus dishing out as much raw damage as possible. We can all adjust when we play.

Feel free to use any/all of the following assumptions:

- Level 18
- Anything that retains its stacks can be fully stacked, since that's your presumption when you acquire it. Rageblade, for instance, does not retain its stacks, so don't presume it would be stacked in any given engagement
- No runes or masteries. Any adjustments from the obvious case of an offensively-specialized set are unlikely to change your item build around.

The short version: Which 4 items give Varus the greatest damage output over, say, 5 seconds? Feel free to answer for either including AoE damage or damage to a single target, but I personally think single target ends up being more telling.

I've scraped together a couple of references that might be helpful, but weren't exactly sufficient to answer my question:

- [Varus' page on the League of Legenda Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Varus_the_Arrow_of_Retribution) which has his base stats, base scaling, and ability information
- [GGChronicle's hands-on discussion from PAX](http://ggc.leaguecraft.com/blog/varus-first-impressions-guide-and-hands-on-analysis-from-pax-east-108.xhtml) which gives some real experiential discussion of Varus

Comment: The champion isn't out for another month at least - what are you expecting people to provide you with?

Comment: All of the champion's stats and abilities are available, and the math is absolutely possible, but I haven't been successful, yet. The minor adjustments that *could* be made to his scaling I doubt will change the final answer significantly. So all I'm looking for is a build of 4 items optimized for damage.

Comment: 4 Doran's shields imo. This is a speculation question which answers could change dramatically before and on release as more information arises.  This sounds more like a giddy for release theorycrafting question than a simple answer solvable one.

Comment: @BrianColvin wouldn't that cover every question here? We're well past the stage where Varus is likely to be dramatically changed moreso than any other champion. In any dynamic/frequently patched game, we have to deal with the possibility of answers here becoming invalidated by changes to the game. In what sense is this different?

Comment: @Deotronic Can you be more specific about what situation you mean? Even if you're just "standing around", damage output at 1 and damage output at 6 are going to vary based on what skills you have available to you and a reasonable assumption about how much gold you have available. A level 1 Bloodthirster isn't something you're going to come across in natural play, so are you assuming level 18 with with a reasonable amount of gold or what?

Comment: This is an excellent question that can definitely be answered with math based on the ability numbers that have been released.  I am baffled as to why this was closed.

Comment: This was closed because it is not a real question. He's asking for someone else to do the math for him, and that's all anyone *can* do, since no one has access to the champion post-PAX.

Comment: This question is for debate on a FORUM not for GSE. You are basically asking the 4 core gear for Varus, which we can't say nothing for sure. If you are going as jungle, or top lane or even sharing bottom with someone. The gear MUST change depending on the opponent. You want AD damage go for 3 BT and 1 IE you got the maximum output. You want good AD and DPS get some PD too. You can't possible want a pre-release core build like this. sometimes you think that the item X or Y is amazing on that champion and when you get it you see that is not that awesome, and a less ranked gear is better.

Comment: That's... not what the question says. It's purely optimizing his damage output, not asking for a core build. A set of items to optimize specifically for total damage output seems to be an issue of mathematics. And yes, I asked for someone with more complete knowledge to answer it for me since I was reasonably unable to do so, which seems to be the point of a Q&A site. There are no questions here that the asker *could not* answer themselves.

Comment: @Deotronic Asking how to get optimal damage out of Varus' combos would be a much better question. Asking which items give "maximum damage" is just math.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Wouldn't the combo to generate optimal damage be just math, too? I'm confused about the difference.

Comment: @Deotronic In an ideal situation, perhaps, but "optimal" is different from Ideal, featuring as much the "when" and the "where" as the "what".